# Send data back to HTML using SimpleHTTPServer

Tags: python, html, post, get, server

I have a form which has a GET action on a button that mimics a login action

```
<div class='row'>
    <fieldset>
        <form method="get">
        <input type="submit" value="Login to Server">
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

I have implemented the do_GET method on the server side that handles this request and gets a token

```
def do_GET(self):
    if self.path == '/index?':
        token = login()
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
        self.end_headers()
        # write out to html?
        # self.wfile.write('<html>') 
        # ...
```

I don't want to navigate to a new page on the submit 
How do I pass the token value back to my html code to display that the login was successful? e.g. as a new label

I'm very new to HTML and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You would need AJAX.